# What is a permissible and effective way to keep one's belongings while praying amidah at the kotel?

Tags: shemoneh-esrei, how-to, kotel-western-wall

What is a permissible and practical way to keep an eye on one's belongings while davening amidah at the kotel, without using lockers etc? I am wondering about both men that have pockets and Women who have bags.

Comment: What kind of putz steals at the Kosel? So sad that these people actually exist. :-(

Comment: What sort of belongings are we talking about?

Comment: Is it not the case that if someone is worried he can hold it so that he will be able to have concentration

Comment: Re pockets, are you talking about concerns about pickpocketing?  (I'm not aware of any requirement to empty them.)

Comment: @hazoriz Thanks! It would be nice if you have the source too

Comment: @ezra, i hope no one ever steals there! just asking :)

Comment: @Yerushalmi https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Berakhot.4.5 , https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.30a.6 , and halacha 5 here http://www.chabad.org/3299180/

Comment: @ezra if someone will die from hunger,  or is an anus (someone will kill him is he does not steel by the kotel) then he is a tzadik to steel (by the kotel)(and please forgive me but that might make you the putz)

Comment: @Yerushalmi Oh believe me the question is a very good one. Why? Because if not about the Kosel, you could ask the same question about airports, subways, etc.

Comment: @ezra primarily I relied on שלוחי מצוה אינן ניזוקין, but you know, it's always good to do some hishtadlut.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I went to the kotel with a bag, I usually put it near my legs or on a chair in front of me. I found this to be the best way to keep in touch with my stuff and to concentrate on the amidah.

Comment: Would there be any problem with _wearing_ the backpack/bag during the Amidah? If it was allowed, that might be a good alternative (especially for those who do not wear a tallis gadol like unmarried men like me).

Comment: it's on your back so you can't see if someone open it.. and it's just not comfortable.. try to bow[?] (לכרוע) with the bag on your back..